# jquery click function slideup slidedown

Tags: jquery, click, slidetoggle

Hi I am trying to do a jquery slideToggle but instead with a slideup and slidedown with click function.

The reason why i don't want to use toggle is because it targets all my links and randomly triggers a nav that is not meant to dropdown.

this is what I currently have i need to have two click function with slidedown when you click the link and when you click the link again it slides up.

```
<script>

      $('#principale li').click(function(e){
    $('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not an issue relating to slidetoggle. it is not targeting random nav menu items it is just not sure specifically which one you want. you are using a class as a selector which is why.

the line:

```
$('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
```

is causing your problem I think. when using a class as a selector, any other elements that match the selector will also be effected. not only the one you are attempting to make changes to. you can assign different ID's to all of them and dynamically pass in the id value to your click function but that isn't necessary as a simple call to $(this) will solve your problem.

without seeing your html this is tough to give a solution but if your menus are nested inside of the list items you can do this.

```
$(this).find('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#principale li').click(function(e){
            $('.sub-menu').slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's a simple fiddle applying the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/rKKcw/

Comment: hi mate that is the same as my previous function its just slower slide :(

Comment: this is wrong. your fiddle is incomplete as it only has one div in it. try putting more divs in there. it will only ever slide toggle the first one.